# How to maintain list names when concatinating the list with a new variable

Tags: r

In the following example, I would like to add a 3rd variable to a list, which is then used as function arguments in an R function (with `do.call`). The problem is that I am unable to maintain the names in the concatenated list, thus allowing for the function to call the correct arguments:

```
# The function (a linear regression)
fun <- function(a=10, b=12, x=1:3){
  y <- a + b*x
  y
}

# Example of function use
x <- runif(20)
plot(x, fun(x=x))

# New list of function arguments
L <- list(a=3, b=-2, c=4)
x <- runif(20)

# Attempts to call function with arguments
args.incl <- which(names(L) %in% names(formals(fun)))
do.call(fun, args=c(L[args.incl], x=x)) # x is not maintained
do.call(fun, args=list(L[args.incl], x=x)) # a and b names are lost
```

#### p.s.

I realize that one solution would be to add `x` to the list `L`, but I do not want to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about

```
do.call(fun, c(L[args.incl], list(x=x)))
```

This way you concentrate `c` the lists `L[args.incl]` and `list(x=x)` to list.

```
> c(L[args.incl], list(x=x))
$a
[1] 3

$b
[1] -2

$x
 [1] 0.29227694 0.42304815 0.90256006 0.91309103 0.43949887 0.64453528 0.48544861 0.09220676 0.48814042
[10] 0.47410596 0.32798225 0.18795248 0.17939297 0.88327417 0.45593052 0.29455631 0.06932314 0.10265696
[19] 0.61977174 0.74408227
```

This does what your p.s. suggests on the fly

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, using `modifyList`:

```
do.call(fun, args=modifyList(L[args.incl], list(x=x)))
# [1] 2.961918 2.071065 2.113825 1.601956 1.931469 2.334662 1.484844 2.943622
# [9] 1.917024 1.838480 1.060532 2.198088 2.451811 2.181310 1.306844 1.397075
# [17] 1.910102 2.940142 2.313939 2.991235
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
do.call(fun, args=c(L[args.incl],x=list(x)))
```

Comment: Three answers in seconds!!